# motivation of group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

I don't understand what's the motivation to define group actions, from what I can understand we associate a group with a set, but that doesn't tell me much. Can I have an example that shows how useful group action is?  Can the set be a lie group ?

Comment: One further example is the proof of the Sylow theorems using group actions. It makes the proof much easier and much better to understand.

Comment: is there a connection between lie groups and group actions ?

Comment: Yes, there is. A Lie group is a group, after all. It can act on manifolds, for example. See [Lie group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_action).

Comment: Good that alone it's important, where can I find some examples  about group actions in lie groups and manifolds ?, what domain studies that ?

Comment: That's differential geometry and Lie theory. Google for "Lie group actions".

Comment: Ok will do,  thanks a lot for helping.